# node.js, mongoose how to find in array of objects by multiple IDs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Node.js with Mongoose module and ran in to a problem.

I have a Schema mockup which looks like this:

```
_id: '',
foo: '',
bar: '',
fb: [{
    id: ''
}]
```

How do I find all objects in collection for matching fb[0].id plus passing in an array of IDs?

I have tried this (find() method with following query):

```
{'fb[0].id': {$in: friendsIDList}}
```

And this:

```
{'fb': {$in: [{id: friendsIDList}]} }
```

And even this

```
{'fb': {$in: {$in: friendsIDList}}}
```

To be more clear, I have an users object which contains their FB data in fb param, but it is an array containing just one object with data.
Now I receive a friend IDs list and want to query all of the user friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB has something called [**dot notation**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) so you can query with `'foo.0.id': 'id'` .

Tested as follows:

```
> db.users.insert({foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', fb: [ { id: '456' } ]})
> db.users.find({'fb.0.id': '456'}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52fb695e403fb143985459dc"),
    "foo" : "foo",
    "bar" : "bar",
    "fb" : [
        {
            "id" : "456"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is the significance of `0` in `fb.0.id` ?

Comment: The id property of the first object in the array of the fb property. Like doing fb[0].id = 456 in most programming languages